# Alternative to custom fields for larger data?

Tags: tabs

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) is great for small values like for a real estate site, one would need to show the features of the property (2 beds, 2 baths, etc..) but when you have more data so much so that each could be a post in itself and needs WYSIWYG editor to write and need to have their own custom fields, I wonder if there's a plugin for that?

For example: a wedding venue.

**Terara Riverside Gardens** (a 'post'):

- Gallery slider with photos ('media' from the post)
- Quick facts ('custom fields')  eg. capacity, rating, known for etc..
- Tabs: [About, Rooms & Decoration, Food & Drink etc..)

Each tab has lots of structured data (reception, transport, ceremony etc..) and not just a few lines text that I could use a custom field for. Like I said, each tab within the venue ('post') is a post in itself.

So my question is: **Is it possible to have each tab as separate posts and then somehow link multiple posts (the tabs) to the main post (the venue)?**

Comment: Take a look at the plugin posts2posts. https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Comment: Thanks, but the author seems to have stopped support and development. Any other similar ones?

Comment: Friendly advise, stick to that plugin anyway. Look at the ratings, and check out who the author 'scribu' is. It won't let you down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posts2Posts can serve you well, but you might also look into wp_editor() for creating multiple instances of WYSIWYG for content that doesn't need its own post.